# Reading HTTP request using TcpListener from Firefox works but not from Chrome or IE

Tags: c#, http, tcp, proxy, network-protocols

I'm trying to build a small web proxy and I ran into some issues with Chrome and IE (Firefox works as expected).

The issue I'm having is that Chrome and IE seem to send some strangely encoded data that is far too short to be an actual HTTP request. 
I didn't trust my code so I ran netcat in listening mode and pointed the system proxy to it, and I saw the same thing again. Firefox sends a full HTTP request while Chrome and IE send a very short garbled string (IE even manages to send my PC user name this way)

Is there perhaps a small "handshake" that IE and Chrome require with the TCP connection before actually sending the http requests? What am I missing? (Also I tried reading both ASCII and UTF8 encodings and nothing seems to help).

Below is a PoC piece of code I use (the code fails reading the first HTTP request line for Chrome nad IE and reads the full request in Firefox):

```
class Proxy
{
    private TcpListener tcpListener;

    private bool IsRunning = false;

    public void Attach()
    {
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8888));
        tcpListener.Start(200);
        IsRunning = true;

        var listeningTask = new Task(() => ListeningThread());
        listeningTask.Start();
    }

    public void ListeningThread()
    {
        while (IsRunning)
        {
            var client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            var clientTask = new Task(() => ProcessClient(client));
            clientTask.Start();
        }
    }

    private void ProcessClient(object obj)
    {
        var tcpClientConnection = (TcpClient)obj;

        while (tcpClientConnection.Connected)
        {
            var headers = ReadHeaders(tcpClientConnection.GetStream());

            foreach(var key in headers.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key, headers[key]);
            }

            // DO Something after this
        }
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, string> ReadHeaders(Stream stream)
    {
        var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);

        var headerline = ReadLine(binaryReader);
        while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headerline))
        {
            var headerParts = headerline.Split(' ');
            headers[headerParts[0]] = headerline.Substring(headerParts[0].Length + 1);
            headerline = ReadLine(binaryReader);
        }
        return headers;
    }

    public static string ReadLine(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();

        byte lastChar = 0x00;
        while (true)
        {
            byte newChar = 0x00;
            try
            {
                newChar = reader.ReadByte();
                memoryStream.WriteByte(newChar);

                if (lastChar == 0x0D && newChar == 0x0A)
                {
                    var lineString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
                    return lineString.Substring(0, lineString.Length - 2);
                }
            }
            catch (EndOfStreamException)
            {
                throw new EndOfStreamException("Reached EndOfStream but the line never ended (no \\r\\n at the end)");
            }

            lastChar = newChar;
        }
    }
}
```